# Changing source collection of ObservableCollection property

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, observablecollection

One of my library classes exposes a property that looks somewhat like this:

```
    Private _myCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of String)

    Public ReadOnly Property MyCollection As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _myCollection
        End Get
    End Property
```

I don't know too much about databinding, but I'm assuming that the framework will automatically notify about changes when items are added to / removed from the underlying `_myCollection` field (correct me if I'm wrong).

What I'd like to know is what happens when `_myCollection` is nulled or replaced with a different collection:

```
    Sub WhatHappensToMyObservableCollectionWhen(updated As Collection(Of String))
        ' nulling underlying field
        _myCollection = Nothing

        ' changing underlying field
        _myCollection = New ObservableCollection(Of String)(updated)
    End Sub
```

Will the framework still notify that `MyCollection` has changed, or do I have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` manually when these things occur?

**EDIT**

I'm asking this question with WPF developers in mind, but I guess the answer will be the same for all observers of `PropertyChanged`. If a GUI written in WPF binds to `MyCollection`, I want to make sure that it is properly updated when the `_myCollection` field changes in the ways that I have described.

Thanks